# Type guard on null not working - TypeScript

Tags: typescript, typeof, typeguards

I have a question. I have used a type guard on a method (the example is the same of TS documentation, at https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html):

```
    function printAll (strs: string | string[] | null) {
        if (typeof strs === "object") {
            for (const s of strs) {
                console.log(s);
            }
        } else if (typeof strs === "string") {
            console.log(strs);
        } else {
    
        }
    }
```

but the compiler doesn't report any error, like documentation sentences.

I expect that strs in

```
    for (const s of strs) {
```

is underlined, because typeof null === "object", and  I should not iterate on a null value.
But the message

> Object is possibly null.

doesn't appear on my Visual Studio Code editor.
Why this?

Thanks for watching.

Comment: Do you have `strict` or `strictNullChecks` set to `false` in your `tsconfig` file?  I'm seeing the error: https://tsplay.dev/mZbvom

Comment: No, I don't have a tsconfig.json. I'm not on a Angular project. I have tested this example on a simple .ts file.